# Keras custom Loss function returning none

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, autoencoder

I am trying to code up an implementation of the variational autoencoder, however I am facing some difficulties regarding the loss function:

```
 def vae_loss(sigma, mu):
        def loss(y_true, y_pred):
            recon = K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
            kl = 0.5 * K.sum(K.exp(sigma) + K.square(mu) - 1. - sigma, axis=-1)
            return recon + kl
        return loss
```

The binary crossentropy part works fine, but whenever I return only the divergence term kl for testing I get the following error:
ValueError: "Tried to convert 'x' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported.".

I am looking forward to possible hints as to what I have done wrong. You will find my entire code below. Thank you for your time!

```
import numpy as np
from keras import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Lambda
import keras.backend as K
from keras.datasets import mnist
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

class VAE(object):

    def __init__(self, n_latent, batch_size):

        self.encoder, self.encoder_input, self.mu, self.sigma = self.create_encoder(n_latent, batch_size)
        self.decoder, self.decoder_input, self.decoder_output = self.create_decoder(n_latent, batch_size)
        pipeline = self.decoder(self.encoder.outputs[0])

        def vae_loss(sigma, mu):
            def loss(y_true, y_pred):
                recon = K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
                kl = 0.5 * K.sum(K.exp(sigma) + K.square(mu) - 1. - sigma, axis=-1)
                return recon + kl
            return loss

        self.VAE = Model(self.encoder_input, pipeline)
        self.VAE.compile(optimizer="adadelta", loss=vae_loss(self.sigma, self.mu))

    def create_encoder(self, n_latent, batch_size):

        input_layer = Input(shape=(784,))
        #net = Dense(512, activation="relu")(input_layer)
        mu = Dense(n_latent, activation="linear")(input_layer)
        print(mu)
        sigma = Dense(n_latent, activation="linear")(input_layer)

        def sample_z(args):
            mu, log_sigma = args
            eps = K.random_normal(shape=(K.shape(input_layer)[0], n_latent), mean=0., stddev=1.)
            K.print_tensor(K.shape(eps))
            return mu + K.exp(log_sigma / 2) * eps

        sample_z = Lambda(sample_z)([mu, sigma])

        model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=[sample_z, mu, sigma])
        return model, input_layer,  mu, sigma

    def create_decoder(self, n_latent, batch_size):

        input_layer = Input(shape=(n_latent,))
        #net = Dense(512, activation="relu")(input_layer)
        reconstruct = Dense(784, activation="linear")(input_layer)

        model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=reconstruct)
        return model, input_layer, reconstruct
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume the error appears when you are "testing"/debugging your training phase, during backpropagation (let me if I am wrong).

If so, the problem is that you are asking Keras to optimize your whole network (`model.VAE.fit(...)`) while using a loss (`kl`) covering only the encoder part. The gradients for the decoder stay undefined (without a loss like `recon` covering it), causing the optimization error.

For your debugging purpose, the error would disappear if you try to compile and fit only the encoder with this amputated loss (`kl`), or if you come up with a dummy (differentiable) loss covering also the decoder (e.g. `K.sum(y_pred - y_pred, axis=-1) + kl`).